# Using async/await with old `Future<Item = X, Error = Y>` types

Tags: rust, async-await

I have a function in a crate that returns old style futures.

Imagine something like:

```
pub fn old_function() -> impl Future<Item = X, Error = Y>
...
```

I want to use this crate in a new codebase where I don't want to mix things too much.

How can I keep the new implementation clean and use `async/await` when calling this `old_function` ?

Comment: Can you not call `.await` on the future it returns?

Comment: `let x = old_function(); let x = x.await;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was very easy. I write here in case somebody has a similar problem. It is actually part of the async/await primer :)

You need to enable the compat feature

```
[dependencies]
futures = { version = "0.3.1", features = ["compat"] }
```

And later it is possible to do:

```
let x = old_function().compat().await;
```