# New Tokio + dependency with older hyper

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, hyper

I am using tokio 0.2.x but I need to use a dependency that depends on hyper 0.12.35.

This result in `SpawnError { is_shutdown: true }` panics.

I have managed to reproduce this in an isolated manner:

cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2.11", features = ["full"] }
hyper = "0.12.35"
futures = "0.1.29"
```

and this is the code:

```
use hyper::rt;
use futures::future as future01;

fn future_01() -> impl future01::Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    future01::ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    rt::spawn(future_01());
    Ok(())
}
```

My dependency has this `rt::spawn` deep into the implementation so that I cannot modify that.

Ideally, I would like to set the default executor used by `rt::spawn` to be the same as the one that `tokio::main` provides. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like to set the default executor used by `rt::spawn` to
>   be the same as the one that `tokio::main` provides. Is that possible?

Not possible, `tokio = "0.2.11"` is able to spawn tasks only if they implement `std::future::Future`, you are not able to create these tasks with `futures = "0.1.29"`, to do you need to use version `0.3.x` or you need to use **compat feature to convert old futures to new one** ([see OP's Q&A for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976639/using-async-await-with-old-futureitem-x-error-y-types/59976867#59976867)).

> This result in `SpawnError { is_shutdown: true }` panics.

The Hyper that you are using uses tokio runtime internally, which is an older version of Tokio(it is also in your `Cargo.lock` with newer version). In Tokio it is not possible to spawn tasks without an initiated runtime, so you need to spawn your task like this :

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    rt::run(future_01());
    Ok(())
}
```

---

**Warning:**

If you still want to use 2 different runtime, one from new and the other from old version, don't use it like below! You'll need to run them in seperate threads.

```rust
//don't use this code!
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    rt::run(future_01());
    Ok(())
}
```

Since `main` is an async and `rt::run` is a blocking function([why you shouldn't call long running code inside async fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735952/why-does-futureselect-choose-the-future-with-a-longer-sleep-period-first) )